# If-else statement correct usage - bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have 3 possible cases for my bash code.

I am creating a bash command, where I have 3 possible options, using flags I assigning to a local variable a value depending on the input parameters, my code depending on the input parameter generates a 1 kind of file, another kind of file or both files.

If to my command I add "-r" parameter I generate 1 kind of file, "red file" , local scripts var take, **activeRed = 1**

If to my command I add "-f" parameter I generate , "feed file" , **activeFeed = 1**

If in my command I use "-rf" I generate both files, **activeFeed = 1 activeRed = 1**

```
        if [[ $activeRed -eq 1 && $activeFeed -eq 1 ]]; then 
            python donwload_files.py --config config-ref-"$market".yml --path_arg $start
            python donwload_files.py --config config-feed-"$market".yml --path_arg $start

        elif [ $activeRed -eq 1 ];then
            python donwload_files.py --config config-ref-"$market".yml --path_arg $start

        elif [ $activeFeed -eq 1 ]; then
            python donwload_files.py --config config-feed-"$market".yml --path_arg $start

        else
            python donwload_files.py --config config-ref-"$market".yml --path_arg $start
            python donwload_files.py --config config-feed-"$market".yml --path_arg $start
        fi
```

As you can see I generate a very simply if-else statement, but I think there is a more efficient way for proccesing this 3 cases, in stead of this "non-visual" and repeat way.

Any idea about creating a more logical or efficient statement?

Comment: Is it `$activeRed` or `$activeRef`?

Comment: is ActiveRed, it was an error while copying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the else block is unwanted, because it wouldn't make sense then.

You can decrease the number of cases to only 2:

```
if [ $activeRef -eq 1 ];then
    python donwload_files.py --config config-ref-"$market".yml --path_arg $start

if [ $activeFeed -eq 1 ]; then
    python donwload_files.py --config config-feed-"$market".yml --path_arg $start
```

You want to run "config-ref" when $activeRef is equal to 1 and you want to run "config-feed" when $activeFeed is equal to 1, so there's no need to make more if-else cases

Answer (score 1):

It is easier. Just process each possibility independently:

```
if [ "$activeRef" -eq 1 ]
then 
    python donwload_files.py --config config-ref-"$market".yml --path_arg $start
fi
if [ "$activeFeed" -eq 1 ]
then
    python donwload_files.py --config config-feed-"$market".yml --path_arg $start
fi
```

For your else clause, when you set the `activeRef` and `activeFeed` vars, make sure that in the case where no parameters had been set, you must set both vars.

```
if [ "$activeFeed" -ne 1 && "$activeRef" -ne 1 ]
then
    activeFeed=1
    activeRef=1
fi
```